# How to access an abstract protected function in Zend

Tags: zend-framework, abstract-class

what can I do to make the abstract function work in the emaillogger class?

```
class EmailLogger extends Zend_Log_Writer_Abstract
```

and I want to use the function _write

```
 protected function _write($event)
 {
      $this->_events[] = $this->_formatter->format($event);
 }
```

then I got this error

Class EmailLogger contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Zend_Log_FactoryInterface::factory)

I am not really sure what to do here
I try'd to use implements Zend_Log_FactoryInterface, but it diddn't work

thanks, Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Zend_Log_Writer_Abstract` implements `Zend_Log_FactoryInterface` which has the following code:

```
static public function factory($config);
```

This forces the `Zend_Log_Writer_Abstract` and any child classes to also have a `factory` method. To satisfy this requirement, you could put in a wrapper method which calls the parent method:

```
class EmailLogger extends Zend_Log_Writer_Abstract
{
    // Add this method in conjunction to what you already have in your class
    public static function factory($config)
    {
        parent::factory($config);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, putting in the empty function worked, it confused me a bit because it wasn't an abstract function, anyway, - learned something again, thanks

Comment: No problem. Interfaces are great for enforcing implementation across any object, abstract signatures are great for enforcing implementation across child classes.